# Gitlab-runner + Docker + Windows - Invalid volume specification

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to run my Gitlab CI locally using Gitlab-runner and docker before committing to make sure they work okay. But I'm having some strange issues!

Unfortunately I have no choice but to use windows (I've had success in the past on Linux).

Every time I run a job in powershell:

`C:/Gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner exec docker npm`

I get an error:

`Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/host_mnt/c/builds/project-0/Users/Lewsmith/api:C:/Users/Lewsmith/api:ro' (executor_docker.go:921:0s)`

I've tried setting docker volumes (nemerous combinations) and builds-dir:

`C:/Gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner exec docker --builds-dir /builds --docker-privileged --docker-volumes "/builds:C:/Gitlab-runner/builds" npm`

That fails with `Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /Gitlab-runner/builds` because of the colon after the C..

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I'm stumped?

Using gitlab-runner version 11.5.0

Comment: Are you using the gitlab-runner shell executor?

Comment: @Rekovni I'm using the docker executor. Shell executor works okay for jobs that run npm install and linter, but I have a test job that requires a postgres service. Services don't work with shell executors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment there isn't official support for the Docker executor in Windows. A work in progress [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/706) is open at the moment, and it looks like some people have managed to get a windows docker executor working to varying success in that merge request.

This [specific comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/706#note_95228056) shows how they've managed to get it setup using a [custom built gitlab-runner](https://notes.alelec.net/blog/post/andrew@alelec.net/Windows-Docker-Gitlab-CI-Runner). I'm unsure how this will work with Services however, so YMMV.

Answer (score 9):

Docker is not fully supported by GitLab Runner on Windows yet.
The workaround is to use **Windows Subsystem for Linux** and install gitlab-runner there:

```
curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner
gitlab-runner exec docker build
```

Comment: seems you need WSL 2 for this to work and that is only currently available in preview releases I believe.

Comment: @JanStanstrup not true, WSL2 was backported to 1903 and 1909 in August 2020.