# How to fix 'Job failed: invalid volume specification' for gitlab-runner exec docker on osx

Tags: macos, docker, gitlab-ci

Getting the error `ERROR: Job failed: invalid volume specification` when trying to run a .gitlab-ci on osx (10.14.5).

```
gitlab-runner exec docker build
```

Complete error:

```
ERROR: Job failed: invalid volume specification: "/Users/xxx/projects/Kubernetes Test/tasks:/Users/xxx/projects/Kubernetes Test/tasks:ro"
```

There seems to be a similar [problem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472481/gitlab-runner-docker-windows-invalid-volume-specification), but found nothing for osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into similar problems, I fixed this by moving the project from

`/Users/xxx/projects/Kubernetes Test/tasks` to `/Users/xxx/projects/kubernetes-test/tasks`

Not a docker expert, but seems that there are issues with spaces in volumes.